# Using a FormSet in a ClassBasedView in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, formset

I'm trying to set up a django form consisting solely of a formset. In forms.py I have:

```
class StudentEnrolmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    school_class = forms.ModelChoiceField(SchoolClass.objects.currently_enrolling())

    class Meta:
        model = StudentApplication
        fields = []

StudentEnrolmentFormSet = modelformset_factory(StudentApplication, StudentEnrolmentForm, extra=0)
```

but I'm unclear how to incorporate the FormSet into a CBV (In this case I've chosen a FormView). In this case I'm basically displaying a table of students, and allowing the operator to assign each student to a class. I only want a single 'submit' button at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will take a look on sources of Django views and check how FormView is working, you find that it just [overrides default get and post methods](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L204) of base View class and adds some additional methods for the [form handling](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L68).

So you can:

1. try to assign your formset to the form_class field of your view and
   play around. Probably you will have to override some additional
   methods;
2. take a look on https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views;
3. if options #1 and #2 causes too much pain - use default View

Comment: ended up using extra-views